# Swapping two non-ETH tokens (e. g. USDC for MATIC) programmatically with Sushiswap SDK (Uniswap V2) via JS

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I'm trying to programmatically swap USDC for MATIC with a JS script. I found this SushiSwap SDK on GitHub (https://github.com/sushiswap/sdk) however it appears to be archived and instructions for swapping non-ETH tokens don't seem to be clear. Can anyone point me in the right direction and/or provide a JS example?